# java thread dump displaying deadlock symptom

Tags: java, multithreading

does jdk 1.2 has capability to display thread dumps (when I execute "kill -3") that contain information on possible deadlocks? Or is this a feature only available for jdk version 1.5 onwards?

Answer (score 0):

The -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak option was added in 5.0, but was also backported to 1.4.2.